# when does a decreasing rearrangment induce an invertible measure-preserving transformation?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, decreasing-rearrangements

Suppose $f$ is a measurable function over $[0,1]$ (for simplicity sake).  Let $f^*$ be the associated decreasing rearrangement function.  We can determine $f$ using a measure preserving map $\phi:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ defined in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X70900387?ref=cra_js_challenge&fr=RR-1) as follows:

$$ \phi(t) = \mu ( \{x: f(x) > f(t) \}) + \mu ( x: f(x) = f(t), \ x \leq t ). $$

It turns out that $f^* \circ \phi = f$. Unfortunately, It is not always the case that $\phi$ is bijective or bimeasurable, i.e., $\phi$ is not a measure preserving transformation.  However, under what conditions is $\phi$ a  transformation?

For instance, it seems to be the case when $f$ is a simple function spanned by characteristic functions of intervals. But what about other such cases?